# How to avoid race condition if user clicks on the element multiple times?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, race-condition

How to avoid race condition if user clicks on the element multiple times? I understand that Javascript is a single threaded language. Could there be any race condition happen?

If so, the best I could come up is to have a flag before the critical section. But from the general concurrency knowledge, there could still be race condition happened if 2 threads enter line 3 together.

```
var isInProgress = false;
$('#target').click(function () {
  if (isInProgress) {
    console.log('In progress, skipping.');
    return;
  }
  isInProgress = true;

  // Critical section start
  ...
  // Critical section end
  isInProgress = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Race conditions *can* happen, mostly when programmers forget about asynchronous functions such as AJAX. This tends to happen more with jQuery users, but even Vanilla JS coders are susceptible to this problem (totally not me, though. No way. I'd never make that mistake. Nope. -shifty eyes-)

That being said, in this case there doesn't seem to be any possibility of a race condition. To demonstrate, use a browser that has one process per tab (ie. not Firefox!) because this WILL crash it.

```
<button onClick="for(var i=0; i<1000000000; i++) alert('Clicked!');">Button</button>
```

The browser will not respond while the click event is taking place, due to the single-threadedness.

Now kill the browser tab. Aren't you glad you didn't use Firefox? :p

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is, as you say, a single-threaded language, so **NO**, there are no race conditions provided your code is sequential.

Answer (score 0):

I typically add a class name to the element, then check for it in the event hander and drop out it it's there. It keeps you from having to pollute the global space with variables.